# Different anchors for tick marks

Tags: pgfplots

To avoid interfering with the graph, I would like to position `-2` with `xticklabel style={anchor=north east},` and `2` with `xticklabel style={anchor=north west},` within the axis environment.  With this code, `-2` is not printed, though.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{axis}[name=plot1,height=5cm,width=5cm,
    clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-3,ymax=8,
    restrict y to domain=-3:8,
    enlargelimits={abs=1},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    extra x ticks={-2},
    xticklabel style={anchor=north east},
    extra x tick labels={$-2$},
    extra x ticks={2},
    xticklabel style={anchor=north west},
    extra x tick labels={2},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]
    \addplot[samples=201,domain=-3:3,blue] {2 * (x - 1)^2 * (x+1)^2 + 1};
  \end{axis}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can have only one list of `extra x ticks`, so the second one overwrites the first. You have the right idea though: use the normal `xtick` for the "normal" ticks and `extra x ticks` for the ones that need special handling.

Comment: You can use {\phantom{2}2} and {-2\phantom{-2}} to create off-center numbers.

Comment: @Paul Gessler  To try to distinguish the labels for the tick marks, I used `ticklabel style={anchor=north west},` for the tick mark `2` and `xticklabel style={anchor=north east},` for the tick mark `-2`.

Comment: @Paul Gessler  Specifically, I added the following commands to the `axis` environment:  ` xtick={2},`  `ticklabel style {font=\tiny,fill=white,anchor=north west},`  `extra x ticks={-2},`,   `xticklabel style={anchor=north east},`,  and  `extra x tick labels={$-2$},`.  It seems that only `anchor=north east` was implemented.  The option `anchor=north west` was for `ticklabel style` and the option `anchor=north east` was for `xticklabel style`.

Comment: @John Kormylo  Yes, that would give me the shift I needed.  I guess just using `\hphantom{2}` for both tick marks would be fine.  I would prefer to use `anchor=north west` for `ticklabel style` and `anchor=north east` for `xticklabel style` if `TikZ` would allow for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make an effort to make your examples more focused. This one did not even compile as you provided it (missing `tikzpicture` environment), and it is much easier to see (and show) what is going on without all that extra styling code that's unrelated to the issue at hand.

You had the right idea, but there was some confusion about when styles are applied. From the code you gave, it looks like you're hoping you can apply different styles to different ticks by separating them. But this is just not how `pgfplots` works: these styles are stored while processing the `axis` options and applied at the time the plot is drawn. This is why you noticed that

> With this code, `-2` is not printed, though.

and later

> It seems that only `anchor=north east` was implemented.

In both cases, you set the same key twice, which means that only the last-set value is used in the plot.<sup>1</sup>

I mentioned one solution in a comment that I will detail here. John Kormylo's suggestion is also good, and one that I use often for quick tweaks to one or a few tick labels. My solution is to use `extra x ticks` for the ticks requiring "special handling" because we can tell `pgfplots` to apply a different style for these extra ticks:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xtick={-2},
  xticklabel style={below left},
  extra x ticks={2},
  extra x tick style={
    xticklabel style={below right},
  },
]
  \addplot[domain=-3:3,blue] {2 * (x - 1)^2 * (x+1)^2 + 1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With this condensed code (removing all extra styling stuff unrelated to the question), it is much easier to see what is going on. First `xtick={-2}` gives a "normal" (non-extra) x tick mark at -2. Then we tell `pgfplots` how we want the "normal" tick labels styled with `xticklabel style={below left}`.<sup>2</sup>

Now we can set up the ticks needing special handling. I use `extra x ticks={2}` to say that I need an extra tick mark at `x=2`. Here we have only one of these, but if there is more than one, the full list needs to go in this one spot. The limitation of this approach is that all the extra x ticks will have the same styling code applied. If you find yourself needing to adjust individual tick labels by different amounts, it's better to use John's method of manually tweaking each one individually.

Finally I specify the style of the extra x ticks with the code

```
extra x tick style={
  xticklabel style={below right},
},
```

Notice that the `xticklabel style` line is nearly the same as before (just changing the positioning), but now we are limiting the setting of that style to only the extra x ticks by setting it inside `extra x tick style`.

The full code above gives this result:

[image]

And, if you want to do your extra styling stuff, here's an example of that. My recommendation is to put everything that's not specific to a particular plot into one style. Then you

- automatically keep consistent style within a document (or further if you want),
- don't have to repeat yourself over and over when writing documents, and
- can easily remove extra styling code when debugging or preparing examples for questions/answers on this site.

Here's an example of that approach. All common code is defined in one place and applied as a single option to each `axis` environment. Then the only additonal options required for each `axis` are options specific to that particular axis.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\pgfplotsset{myplot/.style={ % define all common style here...
  height=5cm,width=5cm,
  clip=false,
  axis lines=middle,
  enlargelimits={abs=1},
  axis line style={latex-latex},
  xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
  ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
  xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
  ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west},
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  myplot, % apply common styling
  %% plot-specific code follows %%
  name=plot1,
  xtick={-2},
  xticklabel style={below left},
  extra x ticks={2},
  extra x tick style={
    xticklabel style={below right},
  },
  xmin=-4,xmax=4,samples=201,
  xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
  ymin=-3,ymax=8,
  restrict y to domain=-3:8,
]
  \addplot[domain=-3:3,blue] {2 * (x - 1)^2 * (x+1)^2 + 1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically `xticklabel style` is a shortcut to *append* to the existing style, but since having both `anchor=north east` *and* `anchor=north west` is impossible, just the last one is used.

<sup>2</sup> The `below left` is a shorthand for `anchor=north east` and it's also much easier for me to visualize quickly. Similar for `below right` versus `anchor=north west`.

Comment: I don't know how I missed `\end{tikzpicture}`.  I had compiled a LaTeX file specifically for this post.

Comment: I understand that this code applies only for labels that are to be associated with two tick marks. Why do you have to specify a style command within a style command - `extra x tick style={xticklabel style={below right}},`?  Without the `xticklabel style={}`,  the label is put `below left` of `2`.  So, I know that the second style command is needed.

Comment: @Adelyn did you read the answer? I explained all of that... `extra x tick style` is needed to limit the scope of `xticklabel style={below right}` to only the extra ticks. Otherwise it would apply for all x tick labels in the axis.

Comment: You didn't code similarly for the `xtick={-2},`.  I am comparing the different ways you style the two tick marks.
To have more consistent code, can I have  `xticklabel style={xticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white,below left}},`?

Comment: I didn't code similarly for `xtick` because that code is not supposed to be limited to only extra tick labels! Why would you want to set `xticklabel` inside `xticklabel`? That doesn't make sense or make anything more consistent.

Comment: To typeset `-2` with the `extra x tick style`, you have `extra x tick style={xticklabel style={below right}},`.  (You have `xticklabel style=` within `extra x tick style=`.)  I agree that it is redundant to have ` xticklabel style={xticklabel style={below left}},`, but it is similar in coding to the other command.  Right?

Comment: @Adelyn having `xticklabel style` inside `extra x tick style` is not the same as having `xticklabel style` inside `xticklabel style`. As I've explained: `extra x tick style` is installed for only the extra x ticks, and by nesting `xticklabel style` inside of that we are saying that we want this setting for `xticklabel style` to apply *only* to the extra x ticks, not any other ones.